# [NSThread start]: Thread creation failed with error 35

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, crash

I have an application where I have to upload data to AZURE from the application. I have to do pagination so I'm saving data as multiple files, files count can go to any number depending upon data. e.g it can more than 1000.

below is my code to split array and upload data to AZURE

```
    //Store All Discreate Data
let pageSize = 25
let splitArray = healthKitDataList.count < pageSize ? [healthKitDataList] : healthKitDataList.chunked(into: pageSize)
for (index,pageArray) in splitArray.enumerated(){
    let array = Array(pageArray)
    let pageNumber = index + 1
    var healthKitDataListJSONData = ""
    if let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(array){
        healthKitDataListJSONData = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) ?? ""
    }
    let allBlobName = "\(prefix)\(AMAzureSyncLevel.all.rawValue)\(identifier)\(AMAzureSyncLevel.page.rawValue)\(pageNumber)"
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    AMAzureSyncHandler.shared.uploadZIPBlobToContainer(for: allBlobName, sampleData: healthKitDataListJSONData) { error in
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
```

Extension

```
extension Array {
   public func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

The problem what I'm facing here is that above for loop is creating multiple threads and at one situation app stops creating threads. And crashes with error [NSThread start]: Thread creation failed with error 35. What is the best way to achieve this.

Comment: loop like that is not creating any threads per se. I think what happens is all available threads are running that async call, which takes a while, and iOS is trying to create more threads, but fails. You need to limit the number of async calls that run concurrently. Consider using `DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform` - that's what it's for, or you can manually control how many operations you schedule at once.